# Finding a Homogeneous Difference Equation Corresponding to a Given Solution

Tags: linear-algebra, recurrence-relations, systems-of-equations

I am currently studying difference equations and came across a problem where I have a solution to a homogeneous difference equation in the form:

$$y_n = (c_1 + c_2n + c_3n^3)7^n,$$

where $c_1, c_2,$ and $c_3$ are constants, and $n$ is the time index. The task is to find the original difference equation that this solution satisfies.

So we can separate the general solution into three solutions:
$$\alpha_1 = 7^n$$
$$\alpha_2 = n7^n$$
$$\alpha_3 = n^27^n$$

In order to do so, I attempted to express it as a system of equations:

$$
A = \begin{pmatrix} 7^2 & 7 & 1 \\ 7^2(n+2) & 7(n+1) & n \\ 7^2(n+2) & 7(n+1)^2 & n^2 \end{pmatrix}, \\
b = \begin{pmatrix} 7^3 \\ 7^3(n+3) \\ 7^3(n+3)^2 \end{pmatrix},
$$

$$

and tried to solve for $Ax = b$.

However, I am struggling to make progress with this approach. Is there a more efficient or standard method for finding the difference equation corresponding to a given solution? Any hints or references would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The homogeneous difference equation is of the form:

$x(n+3) + x(n+2)p_1 + x(n+1)p_2 + x(n)p_3 = 0$

So we need to find $p_1, p_2, p_3$

Answer (score 1):

Analogously to a linear ODE, the difference operator ($\Delta$) should appear as

$$
\left(\Delta-r\right)^3y_n = 0\ \ \ (\text{a triple root})
$$

or

$$
\left(\Delta^3-3r\Delta^2+3r^2\Delta-r^3\right)y_n=0
$$

here $r = 7$ hence

$$
\left(\Delta^3-21\Delta^2+147\Delta-343\right)y_n=0
$$

Comment: Can you provide more steps how you came to this

Comment: If you studied ODE's this result should be familiar: $(D-\alpha)^3y = 0\Rightarrow y = (c_1+c_2t+c_3t^2)e^{\alpha x}$. With linear recurrences occurs the same process.